# Как удалить символы внутри строки?(Dart)

Tags: строки, dart

товарищи! Подскажите пожалуйста,как удалить символ внутри строки? Мне приходит строка и я должен удалить символ посредине. Т.е если приходит 'Dicer' должен удалить 'с', если 'septikor' должен удалить 'ti'. Регистр неважен,спец символов нет.
Спасибо заранее! ;)

Comment: попробуйте произвести декомпозицию вашего вопроса. тут как минимум три отдельных получается: 1. как получить длину строки. 2. как, имея длину строки, получить позицию «символа посередине». 3. как, имея позицию символа, удалить его из строки.

Answer (score 0):

Написал на скорую руку, вроде работает правильно:

```
void main() {
  String s1 = 'Dicer';
  String s2 = 'septikor';
  
  print(foo(s1));
  print(foo(s2));
}

String foo(String s) {
  int length = s.length;
  int center = length ~/ 2;
  
  late String temp;
  
  if(length % 2 == 0) {
    temp = s.replaceRange(center - 1, center + 1, '');
  } else {
    temp = s.replaceRange(center, center + 1, '');
  }
  
  return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Эффективный способ, это фильтрация по кодам символов в UTF-16

Вот тебе пример как оставить в строке только числа, только английские, только русские буквы:

```
/*
 * Filter unicode symbols by code
 * https://gist.github.com/PlugFox/9c7bbfabcea80d41d380b4ee8ae4c75d
 * https://dartpad.dev/9c7bbfabcea80d41d380b4ee8ae4c75d?id=&null_safety=true
 */

import 'dart:math' as math;

const String source = r'#51\J-!dv@dT_o6w^iж,7nдomzGpаWq0ЁKlGsH"~!UZHdпф5i3`N(';

void main() => print(
      String.fromCharCodes(
        source.codeUnits.where((i) =>
            UTF8CodeUnitsX.isDigit(i) ||
            UTF8CodeUnitsX.isLatin(i) ||
            UTF8CodeUnitsX.isCyrillic(i)),
      ),
    );

extension UTF8CodeUnitsX on List<int> {
  /// 0..9: 48..57
  static bool isDigit(i) => i > 47 && i < 58;

  /// A..Z: 65..90
  /// a..z: 97..122
  static bool isLatin(i) => (i > 64 && i < 91) || (i > 96 && i < 123);

  /// Ё:    1025
  /// А..Я: 1040..1071
  /// а..я: 1072..1103
  /// ё:    1105
  static bool isCyrillic(i) => (i > 1039 && i < 1104) || i == 1025 || i == 1105;

  Iterable<int> get onlyDigits => where(isDigit);

  Iterable<int> get onlyLatin => where(isLatin);

  Iterable<int> get onlyCyrillic => where(isCyrillic);

  /// Maximum code
  int get max => reduce(math.max);

  /// Minimum code
  int get min => reduce(math.min);
}
```